# In Cocoa, how to explicitly use UTF-7 for encoding string to use in CC_MD5?

Tags: cocoa

Hello dearest community,

I run into problem of creating an exact MD5 of a string. It must match with MD5 in the PHP and C# counterpart. Reading this : [PHP MD5 not the same as .NET MD5](http://www.ok-cool.com/posts/read/125-php-md5-not-the-same-as-net-md5/), I guess that I must convert first the string using UTF-7 Encoding. But currently I only know that NSString only support UTF-8. This is my code of creating MD5 from a string :

```
-(NSString *) md5:(NSString *) str 
{
    const char *cStr = [str UTF8String];
    unsigned char result[16];
    CC_MD5( cStr, strlen(cStr), result );
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:
        @"%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X",
        result[0], result[1], result[2], result[3], 
        result[4], result[5], result[6], result[7],
        result[8], result[9], result[10], result[11],
        result[12], result[13], result[14], result[15]
        ]; 
}
```

So, if I am not that mistaken, in the line that read `[str UTF8String]`, I must change this into something that read `[str UTF7String]`. Am I correct? If it's is Cocoa have that functionality? Currently my googling didn't give good result for this.

Thanks

Comment: You can make this faster by using `[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]` and asking for the data's `length`. `strlen` is expensive.

Comment: Thanks @PeterHosey. I'll modify my code! But, with what code do you replace strlen with?

Comment: Like I said, ask the data for its `length`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The post you linked to is absolutely incorrect. The MD5 algorithm works on blocks of bytes, it doesn't know anything about what those bytes represent.

All you need to do is ensure that the strings are encoded the same way in PHP, C# and Cocoa. Just use UTF-8. If you do, the MD5 hashes of the bytes representing the strings will be the same.

If you are using UTF-8 on all platforms and the hashes are different then there is likely a problem either with how you're feeding the data to the MD5 algorithm or in the implementation of the algorithm itself. The `CC_MD5` function on Mac OS X should be considered correct.

Comment: Thanks for this information. I'll double check the input to MD5 function. I already check it however, and they both the same : C# and Cocoa. But I didn't have access to the PHP source, so I guess I'll have to rely on the C# source only. Thanks, I'll notify the result of my work.

Comment: you are absolutely correct! And actually, the hash function both in C# and Cocoa produce the same result. I reread the C# again, and .. I miss the step in which before hashing the string, first the string is encrypted! :) -epic failed...

thanks for pointing out the behavior of MD5!